Are there records of complaints about the Roman numeral system that uses letters to represent numbers?
Has any notable historical figure (such as an academic, philosopher, mathematician, or scholar) explicitly criticized or documented concerns about the Roman numeral system's use of letters to represent numbers, specifically citing potential ambiguity or confusion as a drawback?

There is a reverse case.  My vague memory: Soon after Arabic numerals were introduced in Italy, there was a law passed in Florence forbidding their use in commercial transactions: instead numbers must be "written out in letters" (i.e. Roman numerals).

"Roman numerals, which originated as inverted or
halved variants of the Etruscan numerals... underwent further change throughout the late
Republican and Imperial periods, taking the form of the alphabetic signs that they most closely resembled" Chrisomalis, History of written numerals. Clearly, ambiguity was not a concern. Intended reading was typically obvious from context, or they were written cursively. What eventually did in Roman numerals was their unsuitability for doing calculations.

@GeraldEdgar can you provide a source?

@Mauricio I cannot find my copy now.  Raymond L. Wilder, Evolution of Mathematical Concepts.  It  has an image of the law prohibiting use of arabic numerals;

Wilder mentions Struik's "A Concise History of Mathematics", which refers to the statutes of the "Arte del Cambio" from 1299, established by the bankers of Florence. I found that document in La Sorsa's "L'organizzazione dei cambiatori fiorentini nel medio evo". On page 143, it states "CII. Quod nullus de arte scribat in suo libro per abbacum".

@GeraldEdgar perhaps not directly relevant but in his A history of Mathematical Notations Cajori write that "For example, the fourteenth-century banking house of Peruzzi in Florence [...] did not use Arabic numerals in their account books. Roman numerals were used but the larger amounts, the thousands of lira  were written out in words; [...]"
